# object detection on AIY vision kit

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am working on the AIY vision kit and trying to implement object detection in a video stream.
I have tried following the method posted on the AIY website(https://aiyprojects.withgoogle.com/) but seem to be facing a problem when I try to convert the model using the bonnet model compiler.
This is a brief summary of the steps I followed:

1. create annotations for each image in the training set in xml format(256x256).
2. convert all the images to 256x256.
3. create the tf records.
4. downloaded the base model of ssd_mobilnet_v1_coco.config and made the required changes.(set num classes = 2, and path to train and val tf records).
5. trained the model
6. exported the frozen graph to binaryproto format.
   These 5 steps are can be seen by following this link,the same images were used but resized.(https://medium.freecodecamp.org/trackin ... c86419225e)
   all the functions such as create tf record and other related functions can be found in this git repo https://github.com/bourdakos1/Custom-Object-Detection

After I export the model, I get the following error while using the bonnet model compiler

> 2018-08-14 10:39:19.285588: I
>   external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/graph_transformations/graph_transformations.cc:39]
>   Before Removing unused ops: 556 operators, 893 arrays (0 quantized)
>
> 2018-08-14 10:39:19.302398: I
>   external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/graph_transformations/graph_transformations.cc:39]
>   Before general graph transformations: 556 operators, 893 arrays (0
>   quantized)
>
> 2018-08-14 10:39:19.324886: F
>   external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/tooling_util.cc:628]
>   Check failed: dim >= 1 (0 vs. 1)

Comment: Don't post links to pictures of text; copy-paste the message.

Comment: I have pasted the message now

Comment: Please file a bug on [TensorFlow's GitHub account](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues) with your frozen model attached.